# Passing an access and refresh token in the header with IdentityServer4

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core, identityserver4

It seems IdentityServer4 will only pass access tokens as a cookie in the header unless I do resourceownerpassword which will pass an access token, but no refresh token. I need the access and refresh token directly passed in the header something like this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: application/json 
{  "access_token": "eyJz93a...k4laUWw",
   "token_type": "bearer"
   "refresh_token": "sd4rR68..."
   "expires_in":86400
}
```

I've read the entire docs and scoured the internet have found nothing. Is this possible with IdentityServer4?

Edit: 
So I misunderstood what was happening with the token. Now I see it is in the body, I need this in the header.

With this specific need is it better for me to switch to nodejs oauth2?

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer4 does not pass access tokens as a cookie in the header.

If you use the authorization code, hybrid, or client credentials flow, then access tokens are returned from the token endpoint as JSON in the response body.

Refresh tokens are only supported by the authorization code, hybrid, and ROPC flows. To request one include the `offline_access` scope.

Comment: I see that now. Is there a way to pass in the header? Or to include Authorization: Bearer in the header?

Comment: That isn't how OAuth works. The token payload can only return in the body (or as a query param if you're using an implicit flow).

Comment: Thanks for your insight, again. Would I be able to add custom key value pairs to the return body? Like a Organization ID?